# Nginx How to rewrite a path ending with a .jpg extension

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

How to rewrite a path ending with a .jpg extension
from https://example.com/something/something/**image.jpg**
or https://example.com/something/something/something/something/**image.jpg**
to
https://example.com/**image.jpg**
but do not rewrite https://example.com/image.jpg

Comment: Thanks, it works greate!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the character class `[^/]` to match any character that is not a `/`.

Any URI that contains at least one character before a `/` will not match `/image.jpg`.

For example:

```
rewrite .(/[^/]+\.jpg)$ $1 permanent;
```